# How to temporary hide stdout or stderr while running a unittest in Python

Tags: python

I have a faulty third party python module that is outputing to stdout or stderr while it is imported and this is breaking the output of my unittests.

How can I temporary redirect the `stdout` in order to hide its output.

Limit to Python 2.5 syntax :)

**Update**, I forgot to mention that `sys.stdout` and `sys.__stderr__` methods do not work in this case. As far as I know this faulty module is using native code.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do it something like this:

```
>>> import sys, os
>>> _stderr = sys.stderr
>>> _stdout = sys.stdout
>>> null = open(os.devnull,'wb')
>>> sys.stdout = sys.stderr = null
>>> print("Bleh")
>>> sys.stderr = _stderr
>>> sys.stdout = _stdout
>>> print("Bleh")
Bleh
```

Comment: Your example should work, I even tried to change `sys.__stdout__` and `sys.__stderr__` but still I get the output `:[`

Answer (score 22):

You can also use [`mock`](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/) to let you patch `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr` for you when the module is imported. An example of a testing module that using this strategy would be:

```
import os
devnull = open(os.devnull, 'w')

from mock import patch
with patch('sys.stdout', devnull):
    with patch('sys.stderr', devnull):
        import bad_module

# Test cases writen here
```

where `bad_module` is the third party module that is printing to `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr` when is being imported.

Comment: Would this `mock` part of the solution work if the `stdout` is being written to during import as the OP indicated?

Comment: @MattH You're right, the example is wrong. I've udpated my answer to patch sys.stdout and sys.stderr only when the module is imported. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: +1 Interesting, I'm not familiar with `mock`. I guess you don't need the `import unittest` anymore though.

Comment: @MattH I agree. I've removed that import from the example. Thanks again.

Comment: You can use ``from contextlib import nested`` to write the ``with`` close more compactly as ``with nested(patch('sys.stdout', devnull), patch('sys.stderr', devnull)):``

Comment: I like the 'with patch' context manager - I was trying to trap ftplib's stdout when in debug mode. Thanks for that.