# Capturing Scapy function output in Python

Tags: python, scapy

I am trying to capture the output of a scapy function (traceroute) to a string in a python script. I understand I need to pipe this function to stdout (as you do with subproces.call() but unsure how to do this using scapy, is anybody able to provide any assistance? I am new to Python.

Relevent code below.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from scapy.all import traceroute

traceroute('www.google.com')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also call traceroute like this:

```
trace, _ = traceroute("www.example.org", verbose=0)
# trace.get_trace() returns a rather impractical format, so we need
# to convert it. First, we only want the first trace available
hosts = trace.get_trace().values()[0]

# hosts will be in the format { 1: ("1.2.3.4",     False), 
#                               2: ("10.20.30.40", False) ... }
# We convert it to ["1.2.3.4", "10.20.30.40", ...] here:
ips = [hosts[i][0] for i in range(1, len(hosts) + 1)]
```

After which the `ips` variable will contain a list of the hosts that are part of the trace.

Comment: Oh great this looks like the perfect solution, can you explain the second line for me I am unsure where you got the class 'a' from

Comment: of course it should be `trace`. Editing it and adding a few comments also

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by patching `sys.stdout` with a file-like object (for example `StringIO`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python                              
from scapy.all import traceroute
from StringIO import StringIO
import sys

stdout = StringIO()
sys.stdout = stdout
result, unanswered = traceroute('www.google.com')
sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__

print 'Captured stdout:', stdout.getvalue()
```

Anyway, please note that the information that you need is probably already in the objects returned by the `traceroute` method:

```
print result.summary()                                      
print unanswered.summary()
```

Note: You can find more information about patching the standard output in the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8522689/183066).