# Capturing Scapy function show_interfaces() output in Python

Tags: python, output, scapy

i find this link

[Capturing Scapy function output in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610172/capturing-scapy-function-output-in-python)

but this help not for me..

show_interfaces() is good working in cmd.

but it is not working in console..

i want to get output string show_interfaces():

```
from scapy.arch.windows import show_interfaces
show_interfaces()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can look in the source code of Scapy,
and you will find the show_interfaces function.

```
def show_interfaces(resolve_mac=True):
    """Print list of available network interfaces"""
    return IFACES.show(resolve_mac)
```

To get a python dict with the information about the interfaces. I used

```
IFACES.data
```

From here you can convert it to string if you want to.